# Scipy minimize producing random broadcast errors

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, neural-network, array-broadcasting

I am trying to make a very simple `neural network` to play `2048`, but I keep getting errors when running the `scipy` optimizer. When running the network with the function

```
NN_game
```

using weights of the same shape that I used in the optimizer, I have no issues.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import NxN_2048 as game
import pickle, os, time

def gamestart(n):
    return game.new_elements([[0] * n] * n)

def activation(weight, input_layer):
    matmul = np.matmul(weight, input_layer)
    pos = 1 * (matmul > 0)
    neg = 0.1 * (matmul <= 0)
    return (pos + neg) * matmul + 1

def NN_move(board,w1,w2,w3):
    flat_board = np.array(board).flatten().astype(np.float32) #flat_board has size (n**2, 1)
    h1 = activation(w1, flat_board) #h1 has shape (n, 1)
    #print(h1.shape)
    h2 = activation(w2, h1) #h2 has shape (2*n, 1)
    #print(h2.shape)
    h3 = activation(w3, h2) #h3 has shape (4, 1)
    #print(h3.shape)
    move_func = [game.shiftup,game.shiftdown,game.shiftleft,game.shiftright]
    while True:
        if move_func[np.argmax(h3)](board) != board:
            l = ['up','down','left','right']
            #print(l[np.argmax(h3)])
            return move_func[np.argmax(h3)](board)
        else:
            h3[np.argmax(h3)] = np.NINF

def NN_game(w1,w2,w3):
    board = gamestart(4)
    while game.shiftup(board)!=board or game.shiftdown(board)!=board or game.shiftleft(board)!=board or game.shiftright(board)!=board:
        board = NN_move(board,w1,w2,w3)
        board = game.new_elements(board)
    score = sum(sum(np.array(board)))
    return score

def NN_game_packed_args(args):
    return NN_game(args[0], args[1], args[2])

def NN_train():
    n = 4
    w1 = np.random.randn(n, n**2)
    w2 = np.random.randn(2*n, n)
    w3 = np.random.randn(4, 2*n)
    lambda_ = 10

    #game_score = NN_game_packed_args([w1,w2,w3])
    #print(game_score)

    def cross_entropy(args):
        game_score = NN_game_packed_args(args)
        return game_score + lambda_ * (sum(sum(args[0])) + sum(sum(args[1])) + sum(sum(args[2])))

    for i in range(10000):
        results = opt.minimize(cross_entropy, (w1,w2,w3) , method='BFGS')
        print(results.x[0].shape, results.x[1].shape, results.x[2].shape)
        w1,w2,w3 = results.x[0],results.x[1],results.x[2]
        if i % 1 == 0:
            print('Iterations:', str(i),'       |       Current scoring:', str(NN_game_packed_args((w1,w2,w3))))

    return w1,w2,w3

NN_train()
```

I am trying to use `scipy.optimize.minimize` to minimise to minimise cross entropy (under the NN_train function), but I get an error saying

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
>   (4,16) (8,4)

This is despite the code working sometimes, and after 1 iteration, this error will show up. I've checked that the shapes of the activation layers that I am using are correct, so I am not too sure what's going on.

I uploaded the other file that I am using for generating the board [here](https://github.com/yzhilong/2048-game/tree/master)

Comment: You don't give us enough information to help you.

Comment: May I know what information do you think would help? I posted everything that I am using to generate the game and the code that I am using to build the neural network already. Not too sure what I am missing, but then again I am quite new to all of these

Comment: The only way I could help is copy your code, run it, and see exactky where the error occurs.  Then start adding diagnostic prints to check the shapes of the variables involved. And continue with that until I understand why. But I can't run your code in my head or on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the documentation of [numpy.matmul](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) and if this is really what you want. Maybe changing your activation to

```
def activation(weight, input_layer):
    matmul = weight.dot(input_layer)
    pos = 1 * (matmul > 0)
    neg = 0.1 * (matmul <= 0)
    return (pos + neg) * matmul + 1
```

will remove these broadcasting errors? This is due to the fact that numpy.matmul does not behave according to ones intuition.

Comment: The errors are still there. I don't think this is the part causing the errors cause both inputs into

        np.matmul

are 2d matrices. Anyways I tried changing it to what you suggested and the error still occurs. I think the error might have something to do with how scipy.opt.minimize works, but I really have no idea how to test it out since everything else seems to work ok until I get to optimizing the inputs